# pass arguments of make commands

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, makefile

I have a sequence of `make` commands to upload zip file to s3 bucket and then update the lambda function reading that s3 file as source code. Once I update the lambda function, I wish to publish it and after publishing it, I want to attach an event to that lambda function using lambda bridge.
I can do most of these commands automatically using `make`. For example:

```
clean:
    @rm unwanted_build_files.zip

build-lambda-pkg:
    mkdir pkg
    cd pkg && docker run #something something
    cd pkg && zip -9qr build.zip
    cp pkg/build.zip .
    rm pkg

upload-s3:
    aws s3api put-object --bucket my_bucket \
    --key build.zip --body build.zip

update-lambda:
    aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my_lambda \
    --s3-bucket my_bucket \
    --s3-key build.zip

publish-lambda:
    aws lambda publish-version --function-name my_lambda

## I can get "Arn" value from publish-lambda command. publish-lambda ##returns a json (or I would say it prints a json type structure on cmd) which has one key as "FunctionArn"
attach-event:
    aws events put-targets --rule rstats-post-explaination-at-10pm-ist \
    --targets "Id"="1","Arn"="arn:aws:lambda:::function/my_lambda/version_number"

## the following combines the above command into single command
build-n-update: clean build-lambda-pkg upload-s3 update-lambda
```

I am stuck at the last step i.e. to combine and include `publish-lambda` and `attach-event` in the `build-n-update` command. The problem is I am unable to pass argument from previous command to next command. I will try to explain it better:
`publish-lambda` prints a json style output on terminal:

```json
{
    "FunctionName": "my_lambda",
    "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:12345:function:my_lambda:5",
    "Runtime": "python3.6",
    "Role": "arn:aws:iam::12345:role/my_role",
    "Handler": "lambda_function.lambda_handler",
    "CodeSize": 62403592,
    "Description": "",
    "Timeout": 180,
    "MemorySize": 512,
    "LastModified": "2021-02-28T17:34:04.374+0000",
    "CodeSha256": "ErfsYHVMFCQBg4iXx5ev9Z0U=",
    "Version": "5",
    "Environment": {
        "Variables": {
            "PATH": "/var/task/bin",
            "PYTHONPATH": "/var/task/src:/var/task/lib"
        }
    },
    "TracingConfig": {
        "Mode": "PassThrough"
    },
    "RevisionId": "49b5-acdd-c1032aa16bfb",
    "State": "Active",
    "LastUpdateStatus": "Successful"
}
```

I wish to extract function arn from the above output stored in key `"FunctionArn"` and use it in the next command i.e. `attach-event` as `attach-event` has a `--targets` argument which takes the `"Arn"` of last published function.

Is it possible to do in single command?
I have tried to experiment a bit as follows:

```
build-n-update: clean build-lambda-pkg upload-s3 update-lambda
    make publish-lambda | xargs jq .FunctionArn -r {}
```

But this throws an error:

```
jq: Unknown option --function-name
```

Please help

Comment: Instead of trying to capture the output of the publish_lambda and parse the ARN, maybe simply describe the Lambda function to retrieve the function ARN like `aws lambda get-function --function-name my_lambda--query "Configuration.FunctionArn" --output text`. Store that in a make environment variable and use as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, running:

```
make publish-lambda | xargs jq .FunctionArn -r {}
```

will print the command to be run, then the output of the command (run it yourself from you shell prompt and see).  Of course, `jq` cannot parse the command line make prints.

Anyway, what would be the goal of this?  You'd just print the function name to stdout and it wouldn't do you any good.

You basically have two choices: one is to combine the two commands into a single make recipe, so you can capture the information you need in a shell variable:

```
build-n-update: clean build-lambda-pkg upload-s3 update-lambda
        func=$$(aws lambda publish-version --function-name my_lambda \
                | jq .FunctionArn -r); \
        aws events put-targets --rule rstats-post-explaination-at-10pm-ist \
          --targets "Id"="1","Arn"="$$func"
```

The other alternative is to redirect the output of publish-version to a file, then parse that file in the attach-event target recipe:

```
publish-lambda:
        aws lambda publish-version --function-name my_lambda > publish.json

attach-event:
        aws events put-targets --rule rstats-post-explaination-at-10pm-ist \
             --targets "Id"="1","Arn"="$$(jq .FunctionArn -r publish.json)"
```